# Problem with a homework task in Java, involving arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem with the following task.

I should use a char array in [5][5] size and render the following with it.

```
o o o o o
o o o o o
= = = = = 
u u u u u 
u u u u u
```

By now, i got this far.

```
u u u u u
o u u u u
o o u u u
o o o u u
o o o o u
```

Which is not the desired result.

How can I check the array, when it is above the middle, or underneath it?

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char top = 'o';
        char bot = 'u';
        char[][] ar = new char[5][5];


        fillArray(ar, top, bot);
    }


    public static void fillArray(char[][] nArray, char top, char bot) {

        for(int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++)
        {
            Arrays.fill(nArray[i], 'o');
            for(int j = 0; j < nArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                Arrays.fill(nArray[j], 'u');
                System.out.print(" " + nArray[i][j] );
            }
                System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is a 5*5 array supposed to contain 30 elements?

Comment: I'm sorry, it probably is just looking more than it is, just copied it from my homework file. It should be 25 elements of course.

Comment: So you want to fill a 5 x 5 matrix in which the first fows ar filled with `o`'s, the middle row with `=` and the remaining rows with `u`?

Comment: Yeah exactly, i should be able to adjust the size of the array to something like [9][9] and it should display the same, just with more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of middle element to know when to place the line of `===`. This is the general idea based on your code, but consider what will happen when you initialize an array with even numbers such as `char[][] ar = new char[10][10];`.

```
int mid = nArray.length / 2;

for(int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++){
    if (i > mid){ // line is past mid point, fill it with 'u'
        Arrays.fill(nArray[i], 'u');
    } else if (i == mid){ // line is mid point, fill it with `===`
        Arrays.fill(nArray[i], '=');
    } else { // line is before mid point, fill it with `o`
        Arrays.fill(nArray[i], 'o');
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < nArray.length; j++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nArray[j]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine, toString is formatting it like this [ u, u, u, u, u], right?

Comment: At that part we are just looping through the outer layer of the 2-D array, and printing it line by line. In the 5x5 example you posted, `nArray[0] and [1]` would be the `o` lines and `nArray[2]` would be the `===` line, and so on. Feel free to read more about `toString` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the number of rows and columns are always of the same length and that length is an odd number, you can fill the array as follows:

```
public static char[][] fillArray(char[][] array, char upper, char lower) {
    int upperLimit = array.length / 2;
    int middle = upperLimit + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (i < upperLimit) {
                array[i][j] = upper;
            } else if (i == middle - 1) {
                array[i][j] = '=';
            } else {
                array[i][j] = lower;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also thank you for your answer, i don't know how i can't see something like this.